# Error a instalar npm en laravel 5.7.29

Tags: laravel-5, npm

Cuento con el siguiente problema a la hora de instalar npm en un proyecto de laravel el cual su versión es la 5.7.29. Y es necesario instalar estos paquetes de node para poder hacer uso de una nueva herramienta que intento implementar (TinyMCE). El problema está que al ejecutar el comando

```
npm install
```

en el proyecto arroja una serie de errores.

```
6205 error code 1
6206 error path C:\wamp64\www\catastro_sabanalarga\node_modules\node-sass
6207 error command failed
6208 error command C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe /d /s /c C:\Users\DELL\AppData\Local\Temp\postinstall-c881b995.cmd
6209 error Building: C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe C:\wamp64\www\catastro_sabanalarga\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js rebuild --verbose --libsass_ext= --libsass_cflags= --libsass_ldflags= --libsass_library=
6210 error gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
6210 error gyp verb cli [
6210 error gyp verb cli   'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe',
6210 error gyp verb cli   'C:\\wamp64\\www\\catastro_sabanalarga\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js',
6210 error gyp verb cli   'rebuild',
6210 error gyp verb cli   '--verbose',
6210 error gyp verb cli   '--libsass_ext=',
6210 error gyp verb cli   '--libsass_cflags=',
6210 error gyp verb cli   '--libsass_ldflags=',
6210 error gyp verb cli   '--libsass_library='
6210 error gyp verb cli ]
6210 error gyp info using node-gyp@3.8.0
6210 error gyp info using node@16.16.0 | win32 | x64
6210 error gyp verb command rebuild []
6210 error gyp verb command clean []
6210 error gyp verb clean removing "build" directory
6210 error gyp verb command configure []
6210 error gyp verb check python checking for Python executable "python2" in the PATH
6210 error gyp verb `which` failed Error: not found: python2
6210 error gyp verb `which` failed     at getNotFoundError (C:\wamp64\www\catastro_sabanalarga\node_modules\which\which.js:13:12)
6210 error gyp verb `which` failed     at F (C:\wamp64\www\catastro_sabanalarga\node_modules\which\which.js:68:19)
6210 error gyp verb `which` failed     at E (C:\wamp64\www\catastro_sabanalarga\node_modules\which\which.js:80:29)
6210 error gyp verb `which` failed     at C:\wamp64\www\catastro_sabanalarga\node_modules\which\which.js:89:16
6210 error gyp verb `which` failed     at C:\wamp64\www\catastro_sabanalarga\node_modules\isexe\index.js:42:5
6210 error gyp verb `which` failed     at C:\wamp64\www\catastro_sabanalarga\node_modules\isexe\windows.js:36:5
6210 error gyp verb `which` failed     at FSReqCallback.oncomplete (node:fs:198:21)
6210 error gyp verb `which` failed  python2 Error: not found: python2
6210 error gyp verb `which` failed     at getNotFoundError (C:\wamp64\www\catastro_sabanalarga\node_modules\which\which.js:13:12)
6210 error gyp verb `which` failed     at F (C:\wamp64\www\catastro_sabanalarga\node_modules\which\which.js:68:19)
6210 error gyp verb `which` failed     at E (C:\wamp64\www\catastro_sabanalarga\node_modules\which\which.js:80:29)
6210 error gyp verb `which` failed     at C:\wamp64\www\catastro_sabanalarga\node_modules\which\which.js:89:16
6210 error gyp verb `which` failed     at C:\wamp64\www\catastro_sabanalarga\node_modules\isexe\index.js:42:5
6210 error gyp verb `which` failed     at C:\wamp64\www\catastro_sabanalarga\node_modules\isexe\windows.js:36:5
6210 error gyp verb `which` failed     at FSReqCallback.oncomplete (node:fs:198:21) {
6210 error gyp verb `which` failed   code: 'ENOENT'
6210 error gyp verb `which` failed }
6210 error gyp verb check python checking for Python executable "python" in the PATH
6210 error gyp verb `which` succeeded python C:\Python310\python.EXE
6210 error gyp ERR! configure error 
6210 error gyp ERR! stack Error: Command failed: C:\Python310\python.EXE -c import sys; print "%s.%s.%s" % sys.version_info[:3];
6210 error gyp ERR! stack   File "<string>", line 1
6210 error gyp ERR! stack     import sys; print "%s.%s.%s" % sys.version_info[:3];
6210 error gyp ERR! stack                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
6210 error gyp ERR! stack SyntaxError: Missing parentheses in call to 'print'. Did you mean print(...)?
6210 error gyp ERR! stack 
6210 error gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.exithandler (node:child_process:398:12)
6210 error gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (node:events:527:28)
6210 error gyp ERR! stack     at maybeClose (node:internal/child_process:1092:16)
6210 error gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:302:5)
6210 error gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 10.0.19044
6210 error gyp ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\wamp64\\www\\catastro_sabanalarga\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js" "rebuild" "--verbose" "--libsass_ext=" "--libsass_cflags=" "--libsass_ldflags=" "--libsass_library="
6210 error gyp ERR! cwd C:\wamp64\www\catastro_sabanalarga\node_modules\node-sass
6210 error gyp ERR! node -v v16.16.0
6210 error gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.8.0
6210 error gyp ERR! not ok 
6210 error Build failed with error code: 1
6211 verbose exit 1
6212 timing npm Completed in 39539ms
6213 verbose unfinished npm timer reify 1659043711039
6214 verbose unfinished npm timer reify:build 1659043746885
6215 verbose unfinished npm timer build 1659043746889
6216 verbose unfinished npm timer build:deps 1659043746890
6217 verbose unfinished npm timer build:run:postinstall 1659043747752
6218 verbose unfinished npm timer build:run:postinstall:node_modules/node-sass 1659043747881
6219 verbose code 1
6220 error A complete log of this run can be found in:
6220 error     C:\Users\DELL\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2022-07-28T21_28_30_957Z-debug-0.log
```

Al ver mi package.json que contiene mi proyecto note que no existe la dependencia de node-sass ya que es uno de los primeros errores que aparece y tampoco que es que requiera sass en el proyecto.

Este es mi package.json

```
{
    "private": true,
    "scripts": {
        "dev": "npm run development",
        "development": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js",
        "watch": "npm run development -- --watch",
        "watch-poll": "npm run watch -- --watch-poll",
        "hot": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack-dev-server/bin/webpack-dev-server.js --inline --hot --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js",
        "prod": "npm run production",
        "production": "cross-env NODE_ENV=production node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --no-progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "axios": "^0.18",
        "bootstrap": "^4.0.0",
        "cross-env": "^5.1",
        "jquery": "^3.2",
        "laravel-mix": "^2.0",
        "lodash": "^4.17.5",
        "popper.js": "^1.12",
        "vue": "^2.5.17"
    }
}
```

alguien sabe a que se debe este problema y como puedo solucionarlo.
Gracias!

Comment: El error habla de Python, no se SASS: `failed Error: not found: python2`. Al parecer no tienes Python instalado o falta que el mismo esté bien configurado. De hecho, al ser un proyecto Laravel 5.x, las dependencias son antiguas y pide Python 2, siendo que tienes instalado Python 3. Supongo que tendrás que instalar Python 2 y usar entornos virtuales para aislar el proceso de `build` de tu proyecto con `npm`

Answer (score 0):

Yo tuve el mismo problema. Creé el proyecto **laravel 5.7** y ejecuté el comando `php artisan make:auth`, después intenté `npm install` y me daba los mismos fallos que a ti. Lo solucioné haciendo el `npm install` en primer lugar antes del `php artisan mak:auth`, solucionado se me instaló perfectamente, espero que te ayude.